# running multiple commands through ssh and storing the outputs in different files

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, command

i've set up my public and private keys and have automated ssh login. I want to execute two commands say command1 and command2 in one login session and store them in files command1.txt and command2.txt **on the local machine.**

i'm using this code

`ssh -i my_key user@ip 'command1 command2'` and the two commands get executed in one login but i have no clue as to how to store them in 2 different files.

I want to do so because i dont want to repeatedly ssh into my remote host.

Comment: What is the problem with repeatedly ssh-ing into the remote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you can parse the actual outputs of the two commands and distinguish which is which, you can't. You will need two separate ssh sessions:

```
ssh -i my_key user@ip command1 > command1.txt
ssh -i my_key user@ip command2 > command2.txt
```

You could also redirect the outputs to files on the remote machine and then copy them to your local machine:

```
ssh -i my_key user@ip 'command1 > command1.txt; command2 > command2.txt'
scp -i my_key user@ip:'command*.txt' .
```

Comment: this would login twice.  i want to execute it in one login session.

Comment: yeah its a doable solution. But i would also have to remove the txt files from the remote server. So for say 1 command i would have to perform 3 operations and this code would helpful if i needed 3 or more commands. Ill accept your answer if i dont get a better one. thanks

Comment: aah my bad, i dont have to remove them from the remote machine. it will keep being over written. k cool. your solution will do as it involves 2 operations. 1 would be best but 2 is fine. thanks

Comment: @lanzz, but still the files will be saved in remote box but I believe OP is asking for saving the file(s) locally... right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, they are saved remotely and then transferred to the local machine.

Answer (score 4):

NO, you will have to do it separately in separate command (multiple login) as already mentioned by @lanzz. To save the output in local, do like

```
ssh -i my_key user@ip "command1" > .\file_on_local_host.txt
```

In case, you want to run multiple command in a single login, then jot all your command in a script and then run that script through SSH, instead running multiple command.

Comment: erm. In this case i would have to transfer the script to the remote machine

Comment: Still a valid option i guess.

Comment: @ganducoder, Yep you will have to but in that way you can run even 1000 command together in a single shot.

Comment: oh wait, the output would be stored in a single file. Your solution wont work

Comment: @ganducoder, if you are going by the script way then you can save output of all command directly like `command > out.txt` inside the script but only thing is all the o/p files will be stored in remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but probably more trouble than it's worth.  If you can generate a unique string that is guaranteed not to be in the output of command1, you can do:

```
$ ssh remote 'cmd1; echo unique string; cmd2' |
  awk '/^unique string$/ { output="cmd2"; next } { print > output }' output=cmd1
```

This simply starts printing to the file `cmd1`, and then changes output to the file `cmd2` when it sees the unique string.  You'll probably want to handle stderr as well.  That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.  Assuming you can set up authentication from the remote machine back to the local machine, you can use ssh to pipe the output of the commands back. The trick is getting the backslashes right.

```
ssh remotehost command1 \| ssh localhost cat \\\> command1.txt \; command2 \| ssh localhost cat \\\> command2.txt
```

Or if you aren't so into backslashes...

```
ssh remotehost 'command1 | ssh localhost cat \> command1.txt ; command2 | ssh localhost cat \> command2.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

option 1. Tell your boss he's being silly. Unless, of course, he isn't and there is critical reason of needing it all in one session. For some reason such a case escapes my imagination.

option 2. why not tar?

```
ssh -i my_key user@ip 'command1 > out1; command2 > out2; tar cf - out*' | tar xf -
```

Answer (score 0):

join them using && so you can have it like this

```
ssh -i my_key user@ip "command1 > command1.txt && command2 > command2.txt && command3 > command3.txt"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: need the files on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to, here's *exactly* what I did:

```
ssh root@your_host "netstat -an;hostname;uname -a"
```

This performs the commands in order and cat'd them onto my screen perfectly.

Make sure you start and finish with the quotation marks, else it'll run the first command remotely then run the remainder of the commands against your local machine.

I have an rsa key pair to my server, so if you want to avoid credential check then obviously you have to make that pair.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:
At first you need to install `sshpass` on your machine.
then you can write your own script:

```
while read pass port user ip; do
sshpass -p$pass ssh -p $port $user@$ip <<ENDSSH1
    COMMAND 1  > file1
    .
    .
    .
    COMMAND n  > file2
ENDSSH1
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    
____HERE
```

Answer (score -2):

How to run multiple command on remote server using single ssh conection.

[root@nismaster ~]# ssh 192.168.122.169 "uname -a;hostname"
root@192.168.122.169's password: 
Linux nisclient2 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:54 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
nisclient2

```
    OR
```

[root@nismaster ~]# ssh 192.168.122.169 "uname -a && hostname"
root@192.168.122.169's password: 
Linux nisclient2 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:54 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
nisclient2

Comment: badly formatted and I don`t see where you are logging to 2 separate files for each command, i.e. you are just calling two commands